# How to Sort a String Using Java

Tags: java, sorting, bucket-sort

I am trying to sort a string. I have sorted the first letters but the subsequent letters are not sorted. I also need to pad the words that are not same with the longest word with * but I have no clue how to do this. My BASE IS 27. The alphabets and * character for the padding. The current result is 
apple
algorithm
australia
jack
olympic
sell
sleep

I have used a combination of Radix sort and Bucket Sort for this purpose. I am calling the Bucket Sort in the Radix sort. I think the problem is within the BUcket sort implementation.

```
 private static void bucketSort(List<String> S, int d, int i) {     
    while(!S.isEmpty()) {       
        int DIVISOR = pow(BASE, i-1);
        int MODULO = pow(BASE, i);  
        String s = S.remove(S.first());
        int index = (s.length() <= d)? 0: s.charAt(i) - ('a'-1);
        System.out.println(index);
        int value = s.charAt(index); 
        int index2 = (value / DIVISOR) % MODULO;

        buckets[index2].insertLast(s);
    }

    for (List<String> bucket : buckets) {
        while (!bucket.isEmpty()) {
            S.insertLast(bucket.remove(bucket.first()));
        }
    }
}
private static int pow(int base, int i) {
    int pow = 1;
    while (i > 0) {
        pow *= base;
        i--;
    }
    return pow;
}
```

algorithm
apple
australia
jack
olympic
sell
sleep

Comment: It's weird that you use both bucket and radix sort at the same time, since they are fundamentally the same thing.  Can you explain why you do that?  Do you have some theory why this is a good idea?

Comment: Wouldn't there be an integer overflow with your `pow` method? As your base is 27, and `27^7` will give an integer overflow. Can you please describe what the parameters `d` and `i` mean in the method `bucketSort`?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Why did you implement your own comparison/sort function, if you can rely on standard library?

Comment: Apologies for the way I composed my post. The length of the longest word is represented by 'd' and i am iterating through the word using the 'i'. I am calling the buscket sort function inside radix sort. I have decided not to use counting sort function inside radix sort. I wasn't sure you could re-write the entire so as not to break forum rules. I only post on here on and off, apologies for the way I constructed the content.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use existing methods like `Collections.sort`?

```
List<String> S = Arrays.asList("apple", "algorithm", "australia", "jack", "olympic", "sell", "sleep");
Collections.sort(S);
```

Or if you want to specify a lambda sort function:

```
S.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2));
```

Is there some reason why you want padding? the easiest solution would find the maximum length of all strings and add missing spaces.

Comment: Likely the Question is due to is a homework assignment or a learning challenge, not a practical work problem.

Comment: I thought the same, but OP doesn't say anything about limitations or a specific method that must be used

Comment: Then I suggest you post a comment seeking clarification.